# Putting aligned items in the index

Tags: vertical-alignment, indexing

I'm trying to write a text but at the beginning, in the index, the items don't appear rightly aligned. It appears as:

[image]

My code is:

```
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,snakes,shapes.geometric,fit,backgrounds,arrows.meta,decorations.markings,positioning,shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{ a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm}

\tikzset{module/.style={draw, minimum width=#1, minimum height=7mm, font=\sffamily}, module/.default=2cm, >=LaTeX}

\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeindex

\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}


\pgfplotsset{%
    ,compat=1.12
    ,colormap={mygreen}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(255,255,255)}
    }
    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\pagestyle{headings}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark} \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{alfabetico}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{Index}
}

\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{{\thechapter. #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{{\thesection. #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.5\headheight}

\usepackage{anysize}  \marginsize{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}{3cm}

\vspace{-.8cm}}

\sloppy \frenchspacing
\input xy
\xyoption{all}
\newdir{ >}{{}*!/-12pt/@{>}}

\newfont{\hueca}{msbm10}
\def \hu #1{\hbox{\hueca #1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\'Indice}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Cap\'itulo}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliograf\'ia}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{\'Indice de t\'erminos}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\'Indice de figuras}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\'Indice de tablas}

\baselineskip=7,0mm

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\include{Libro_intro}

\pagestyle{headings} \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark} \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark} \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
```

I've tried to change a lot of things, but ever *Índice de términos* are not well aligned.

Thank you very much in advance, sincerely!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Can you please complete your code? Looks like at least the \end{document} got missing ;-) // May be I overlook it, but I do not see commands containing \index{} one way or the other. ?? // Thanks

Comment: Hi, really the complete code is huge. I don't use \index{}. Instead I use \makeindex